# lapply - Create new variables, based on current variables, conditionally based on info in 2nd data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lapply

I've been working on a lot of new projects where I'm doing lots of unfamiliar data prep and management.

I have two data frames: 1) that is very large with thousands of observations and variables (df1), and 2) a data frame that lists ranges of collection years for a subset of variables in df1 (df2). I need to create a new variable in df1 for a large subset of variables/columns in df1. The new variables created for df1 will check if a value is present (1), a value isn't present for a year that was collected (0), or a value isn't present and the year falls outside of the collection range listed in df2 ('NA').

I've spent a couple days reading a ton of `lapply()` but I can't seem to find one that addresses my needs or deals with type of complexity such that I don't have to do this with brute force.

Here is my workable starting data frame:

```
grp <- c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b')
year <- c(1991, 1992, 1993, 2005, 2010)
v1 <- c(20.5, 30.5, 29.6, 28.7, 26.1)
v2 <- c(100.0, 101.5, 105.1, 'NA', 95.0)
v3 <- c(47.2, 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA')
df1 <- data.frame(grp = grp, year = year, v1 = v1, v2 = v2, v3 = v3)
df1

grp year   v1    v2   v3
a   1991  20.5   100 47.2
a   1992  30.5 101.5   NA
a   1993  29.6 105.1   NA
b   2005  28.7    NA   NA
b   2010  26.1    95   NA
```

Here is my reference data frame with coverages for variables in df1:

```
vars <- c('v1', 'v2', 'v3')
start <- c(1989, 2004, 1980)
end <- c(2015, 2011, 1994)
df2 <- data.frame(vars = vars, start = start, end = end)
df2

vars start  end
 v1  1989 2015
 v2  2004 2011
 v3  1980 1994
```

I've been learning with simple stuff with 'lapply()' like:

```
test <- df1[paste0(vars, '.cov')] <- lapply(df1[vars], function(x) as.integer(x > 0))
```

I wrote out in R, what I think are, the types of conditions that need to be met. I'll narrate with written English:

1. a value is present for a year that was collected (1)

   ```
   if (!is.na(x)) { x <- 1 }
   ```
2. a value isn't present for a year that falls within the range listed in df2 (0)

   ```
   if (is.na(x) & year %in% seq(df2$start[df2$vars == names(df1[x]), ], df2$end[df2$vars == names(df1[x]), ], 1)) { x <- 0 }
   ```
3. a value isn't present and the year falls outside of the collection range listed in df2 ('NA')

   ```
   if (is.na(x) & !(year %in% seq(df2$start[df2$vars == names(df1[x]), ], df2$end[df2$vars == names(df1[x]), ], 1))) { x <- 'NA' }
   ```

I did my best with the syntax and indexing, but we're rapidly getting out of my comfort zone.

After running the conditional checks the desired output/modified df1 should look like:

```
grp year   v1    v2   v3 v1.cov v2.cov v3.cov
  a 1991 20.5   100 47.2      1      1      1
  a 1992 30.5 101.5   NA      1      1      0
  a 1993 29.6 105.1   NA      1      1      0
  b 2005 28.7    NA   NA      1      0     NA
  b 2010 26.1    95   NA      1      1     NA
```

I'm open to a variety of solutions but this seemed the likely path to move through. Thanks again for all the help. I'm an experienced R modeler/scientist but I've learned so much data prep, 'data.table', and 'dplyr' in the past month with all your help.

Comment: Use `NA`, not `'NA'`, which is just a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data.table:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
DT = melt(df1, id = c("grp", "year"), meas = patterns("^v"))[, value := type.convert(as.character(value))]

# mark based on whether found or not within collection periods
DT[df2, on=.(variable = vars, year >= start, year <= end), 
  found := as.integer(!is.na(value))]

# also mark if found outside collection periods
DT[!is.na(value) & is.na(found), found := 1L ]
```

which gives

```
    grp year variable value found
 1:   a 1991       v1  20.5     1
 2:   a 1992       v1  30.5     1
 3:   a 1993       v1  29.6     1
 4:   b 2005       v1  28.7     1
 5:   b 2010       v1  26.1     1
 6:   a 1991       v2 100.0     1
 7:   a 1992       v2 101.5     1
 8:   a 1993       v2 105.1     1
 9:   b 2005       v2    NA     0
10:   b 2010       v2  95.0     1
11:   a 1991       v3  47.2     1
12:   a 1992       v3    NA     0
13:   a 1993       v3    NA     0
14:   b 2005       v3    NA    NA
15:   b 2010       v3    NA    NA
```

(`type.convert` is used to override OP's encoding of missing data with string `'NA'`.)

---

The `melt` step only makes sense here because the variables seem to be of the same type (numeric). If they aren't, something similar can be done by looping over each column:

```
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)
for (v in unique(df2$vars)){
  df1[, (v) := type.convert(as.character(get(v)))]

  fcol = paste0("found.",v)
  df1[df2[vars == v], on=.(year >= start, year <= end), 
    (fcol) := as.integer(!is.na(get(v)))]
  df1[!is.na(get(v)) & is.na(get(fcol)), (fcol) := 1L ]
}

   grp year   v1    v2   v3 found.v1 found.v2 found.v3
1:   a 1991 20.5 100.0 47.2        1        1        1
2:   a 1992 30.5 101.5   NA        1        1        0
3:   a 1993 29.6 105.1   NA        1        1        0
4:   b 2005 28.7    NA   NA        1        0       NA
5:   b 2010 26.1  95.0   NA        1        1       NA
```

Comment: Awesome, I'm going to check this when I get back. The variables will almost all be continuous so this will be fine. Anything that's a factor I can do by hand. I really appreciate this, and I will check on it with the full set later.

Comment: This worked on the scaled data set perfectly; just need to take in and understand that for loop a little better. Thanks.